# Suggestions for secure fax SaaS

Tags: network

Does anyone have experience with any fax cloud services, which they can recommend from a security standpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Our realtor used [Transaction Desk](http://www.instanetsolutions.com/transaction-desk.htm) when dealing with our documents, and had us do the same. She would give us a paper with a barcode on it and we dialed the 800# to send our fax to, and made sure that page was the first page in the fax. There's always risk when dealing with cloud based services for obvious reasons, the most obvious reason is that there is a third party *actually storing the data*. I would recommend TD though or use it myself if I needed secure fax services.